# What does something is a security mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Can somebody explain the phrase in bold for me, please?
Does it mean **In terms of security**?

Regulation. Last week, new Securities and Exchange Commission Chair Gary Gensler suggested that the agency may be gearing up for a long-awaited crypto crackdown, telling CNBC: “**To the extent that something is a security**, the SEC has a lot of authority, and a lot of crypto tokens—I won’t call them ‘cryptocurrencies’ for this moment—are indeed securities.”

Source: https://www.forbes.com/sites/jonathanponciano/2021/05/10/ethereum-dogecoin-cardano-cryptocurrencies-propelling-the-market-to-25-trillion/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He is using *security* in its specialised financial meaning - according to Wikipedia, a *tradable financial asset.* That is what the name of the Securities and Exchange Commission refers to.